# Gnuplot label sqrt

Tags: latex, gnuplot, maxima

I'm writing a mathematical course in LaTeX. For plotting, we use Maxima-Gnuplot.
I have a perfect working graph. The label is supposed to contain the formula.
The plot I'm using:

```
sw_draw("
color=\"midnight-blue\",
line_width=2,
explicit(sqrt(x),x,0,5),
yrange=[-5,5],
xrange=[-2,5],
xaxis = true,
yaxis=true,
color=\"midnight-blue\",
label ([\"f(x)={/Symbol @\326\140}x\",-1,2])
")
```

I've read that the label should contain the 326 for the rootsignbase, and the 140 for the line of the root in the top.
I already tried:

- $\sqrt{x}$, which is not working.
- multiple \

Did someone solve this before? I've read through all forums.

Comment: I have no idea what Maxima-Gnuplot is, but in gnuplot+latex single quotes are usually a less involved solution than double quotes, e.g. `set xlabel '$\sqrt{x}$'`. Maybe you can try that.

Comment: Thank you, tried that as well... Did not work.

Comment: I don't understand why all of the arguments are concatenated into a string. What is the function `sw_draw`? What interface are you using? What is the content of the Gnuplot output file (maxout.gnuplot or maxout.gnuplot_pipes)? Can you edit the Gnuplot output file to get the display you want? (That would give us a clue as to how to adjust the arguments in Maxima.)

Comment: I'm guessing that `sw_draw` prints the string to generate a Maxima expression. If so I'm guessing you can try this: put four backslashes in each place that you want a backslash in the label string, i.e.: `label ([\"f(x)={/Symbol @\\\\326\\\\140}x\",-1,2])`

Comment: @RobertDodier thank you for your comment. It did not work though.
output file is in maxima.gnuplot. I'm fairly new to this. But here is a link about maxima plots:
http://riotorto.users.sourceforge.net/gnuplot/index.html

I did solve it, in a way similar to your tip!

Comment: You can use the psfrag latex package (your plots should be saved as postscript). e.g. in gnuplot you put `set xlabel 'sqx'`; in latex you put `\psfrag{sqx}[c]{$\sqrt{x}$}`

Answer (score 0):

We managed to solve the problem. Did write it in different way:

```
user_preamble=\"set label 'f(x)={/Symbol @\\\\326\140}x' at -1,2\"
```

Comment: I'm glad to hear you got it working, although I am surprised that you do not need to put the same number of backslashes before each character code, i.e., `\\\\326\\\\140`. But if it works for you then all is well!